# ggplot2 colour order don't match pie chart order

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

My question is one that I think should be straightforward but I can't see how to fix it. When I do a standard pie chart to see the colours in the order R generates them, I get one colour order but when I use the same rainbow in ggplot I get a different order. Here's a reproducible example:

```
require(ggplot2)
myRainbow <- rainbow(7)
pie(rep(1, 7), labels=letters[1:7], col = myRainbow)
x11()
ggplot( data.frame(x = 1:7, y = 9:3), aes(x = x, y = y, colour = myRainbow[1:7],size = 4,show.legend=FALSE) ) + 
    geom_point() + scale_colour_manual(values=myRainbow, name="Colour_Test", labels=letters[1:7], breaks=myRainbow) +
    guides(size=FALSE)
```

Here's the result I get:

[image: Comparison of orders]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same color order, if you specify them "as is":

```
plot(y~x, data.frame(x = 1:7, y = 9:3), col = myRainbow[1:7], pch=19, cex=3)
ggplot( data.frame(x = 1:7, y = 9:3), aes(x = x, y = y, colour = I(myRainbow[1:7]), size = 4,show.legend=FALSE) ) + 
    geom_point()
```

See `?AsIs` (`I`).

Alternatively, you could do `scale_colour_manual(values=setNames(myRainbow, myRainbow))` to map the correct values to the correct levels.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you know the reason why you have to specify it like that? The only thing I can think of would be RColorBrewer somehow changing it.

Comment: I don't know why the order is changed internally, but `aes(colour = myRainbow[1:7])` does not interpret `#000000` as _black_, but as a character value. `aes(colour = I(myRainbow[1:7]))` sees it as black. Alternatively, to prevent the order from beeing changed, you can pass a named character vector to the `values` argument of scale_. That way, you also ensure, that the character value `#000000` is mapped to the color `#000000`.